# Word for Finally Reaching a Desired State

Tags: single-word-requests

Sometimes, one undergoes a sequence of gruelling trials, struggles, etc., an **ordeal**. But eventually the ordeal is over, and one finally reaches a particular, desired state. What word adequately describes this state?

The best I could come up with was *relief*, *upside*, *goal*, or (reaching a) *silver lining*. However, none of these feel appropriate.

Here's an example: "After enduring the intolerable advertisements, the **_** was in sight for Timmy: in moments, the movie would begin."

Comment: @ElliottFrisch That has a distinctively **negative** connotation; I am looking for such an expression with a **positive** connotation.

Comment: Comments on an answer should be placed within the comments for that answer. (That's the only reason I can think that someone down-voted your question and left it for someone else to guess and explain why they did it.)

Comment: You could use [*telos*](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3Atelos), but only if you felt like being pretentious.  :)

Answer (score 5):

**[payoff](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/payoff)**: a good result; the advantage or benefit that is gained from doing something

**[reward](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reward)**: to give money or another kind of payment to (someone or something) for something good that has been done

**[compensation](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/compensate)**: provision of something good as a balance against something bad or undesirable; to make up for some defect or weakness

**[gratification](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gratifying)**: experiencing pleasure or satisfaction; pleasing, *a gratifying result*

Comment: This is closer than anything else posted yet. Particularly *compensation* is in the vein of the word for which I am looking.

Comment: @Newb - um, then howsabout an upvote for my work? ;) You don't have to select it, just recognize that I tried.

Comment: I did upvote your post. Someone else, I don't know who, appears to have downvoted your post.

Comment: @Newb - Ah, sorry. :(

Comment: It is unfortunate; you certainly deserve some upvotes for your work.

Comment: @Newb - there are a select few here who have a permanent gustatory sensation of sour grapes.

Comment: I upvoted you for *payoff* which is positive and fits directly in OP's sentence.

Answer (score 5):

**Raison d'être**, meaning "purpose or reason for being" may work for you. Of course, this phrase is borrowed from French and commonly used in English.

> After enduring the intolerable advertisements, Timmy's raison d'être was in sight: in moments, the movie would begin.

I have friends who grew up in Hollywood for whom this might literally be an accurate statement, in their opinions. It has the sense of describing an ultimate purpose, and not just some subsidiary purpose at a moment in time.

Answer (score 2):

The "end" was in sight. They arrived at the "terminal". He could see the "goal-post"; the "finish-line". The "summit", the "peak", the "top", the "pinnacle", the "apex".

Comment: Yes, because the *state* has been attained.

Comment: These are closer to the meaning of the desired word, but I am looking for a term with a distinctly **positive** connotation.

Answer (score 2):

I would use simple words such as *the **long-expected** or the **long-awaited** was in sight ...*

Answer (score 1):

Use these phrases appropriately:-

1. Light at the end of the tunnel
2. End in sight

Answer (score 0):

... eventually the ordeal is over, and one finally reaches a particular, desired state. What word adequately describes this state?

```
peace
```

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't sound too poetic, you can try - "After enduring the intolerable advertisements, the **deliverance** was in sight for Timmy." Alternatively, you can use redemption/salvation.

Comment: Explain the reason for down-voting

Answer (score -1):

For an **ordeal**, I would say "survived."

To state something more positively after going through difficulty, I would say "made it through."

Comment: I'm looking for a noun, not an adjective.